# Finding the Transition Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: M_{22} \rightarrow M_{22}$ be defined by:

$$T \begin{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2c & a+c \\ b-2c & d \end{bmatrix}, $$ $B$ be the standard basis for $M_{22}$,

and

$$B' = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \right \} $$

Find the matrix $[T]_B$ of the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the basis $B$.

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how to approach these questions. Any sort of direction would be very helpful.

Comment: The vanilla way to do it is to basically plug in elements of the basis in order to T then express it as linear combo of the elements of the  basis and take transpose.  that is your $[T]_{\beta '}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we map the matrices to four vectors 
$$
\phi(M) = 
\phi \left(
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}
\right) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we have
$$
A \phi(M) = \phi(T(M)) \iff \\
A
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2c \\
a+c \\
b-2c \\
d 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for some matrix $A$ which leads to
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

the basis for $B: e_1 = a, e_2 = b, e_3=c, e_4=d$

$[T]_B =\pmatrix{0&0&2&0\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&-2&0\\0&0&0&1\\}$